# How do I do the labelling of bars with variable name in bar plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I have 2 values, X1= 810 and X2= 830. I need to make a bar plot and have the bars labelled as X1 and X2. I am doing in R. Can someone help out with the syntax?

I tried:

```
a<- 810
b<- 830
data<- c(a,b)
plot1<- barplot(data, xlab = "X", ylab="Value")
```

It works till here. But I also need to label X1 and X2 for the two bars in the plot. Tried this:

```
x <- c(X1, X2)
text(plot1, labels=x)
```

It doesn't work. Can someone help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it's easier to call direct in the `barplot` command:

```
plot1<- barplot(data, xlab = "X", ylab="Value", names.arg=c("X1", "X2"))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks J_F

Answer (score 0):

`text` can do this.  You will need to precisely specify where you want the label. Here is an example placement.

```
text(c(0.7,1.9), 780, labels=c("X1", "X2"), cex=2)
```